Mutate different variables with same structure into one
I have a large dataset that includes several variables named: F12.4.1 ... F12.4.10.
Each of them has the same pattern, where 1 means yes, and 0 means no.
I want to mutate these variables into one new variable that only includes yes, so it would look like this:
F12.4.1 --- 30
F12.4.2 --- 20
etc.
I have created this code:
library(dplyr)
homeschooling <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(yes_count = sum(c_across(c(`F12.4.1`, `F12.4.2`, `F12.4.3`, `F12.4.4`, `F12.4.5`, `F12.4.6`, `F12.4.7`, `F12.4.8`, `F12.4.9`, `F12.4.10`))))

But the end result is for some reason wrong. It lists all the variables but they don't have the correct numbers.
---
Data
set.seed(2024)
data <- replicate(10L, rbinom(20L, 1, 1/2)) |> 
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(paste0("F12.4.", 1:10))


what is the meaning of 30 in F12.4.1 --- 30? probably you mean column sum colSums(data)?

Try this:
data %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = colnames(data)) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarize(count = sum(value))


Instead of listing all the variables to be added, use starts_with.
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(yes_count = sum(c_across(starts_with("F12.4"))))


Using Thomas's suggestion:
data.frame(colSums(data))

Output:
         colSums.data.
F12.4.1             11
F12.4.2             10
F12.4.3              9
F12.4.4              8
F12.4.5             11
F12.4.6              8
F12.4.7             11
F12.4.8              8
F12.4.9             12
F12.4.10             8

